# Laravel shared project codebase

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I've searched a few days now and I don't think I've found a relevant question anywhere.

Is there a way to have multiple "sub-projects/sites" which use a shared codebase for their controllers and models, but have their own routes and views.

For example there would be: public/site1 and public/site2 with their own /views, /routes folder and own .env but would both use the same /app code.

These sub-projects would be all on the same server, so if there would be an other solution where there would be multiple applications which can link controllers and models from 1 main "core" application would be possible too.

EDIT: I'm looking more if there is a way to autoload for example models and controllers from an other location on the server, that way whenever I update the "core" once it gets used on all sub-projects.

Comment: Look at `public/index.php` every app use the same code base should has its own public folder and app folder with correct paths inside that file.

Answer (score 1):

You can create directories and namespaces for each subsite you want with a structure like this for example.

- app

  - Http (for shared controllers)
  - Models (for shared models)
- site1

  - Http
  - Models
- site2

  - Http
  - Models
- routes

  - shared.php
  - site1.php
  - site2.php

You would need to register them in the `composer.json` like:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\Shared\\": "app/",
        "App\\Site1\\": "site1/",
        "App\\Site2\\": "site2/"
    }
},
```

In the `RouteServiceProvider` you can route each route file using a different domain or subdomain and include the `shared.php` for each (for auth routes for example). It could look something like:

```
protected function mapSite1Routes()
{
    Route::group([
        'domain'     => config('sites.site1.domain'),
        'namespace'  => $this->namespace,
        'middleware' => ['web'],
    ], function () {
        require base_path('routes/shared.php');
        require base_path('routes/site1.php');
    });
}
```

This way you have one application with shared and seperate sources.

That should get you started :)

Comment: does this include that whenever I change the "core"-package I don't have to re-deploy it across all sub-projects?

Comment: You are correct, I missed that bit. Changed my answer with a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve actually done this myself. One my own projects is a multi-tenant content management system. There’s the core CMS codebase, but then for each “tenant” I create a package that contains that tenant’s routes, views, resources etc.

Each package is included via Composer and just has the same directories as any other Laravel project:

- /public

  - /css
  - /img
  - /js
- /resources

  - /assets

    - /sass
  - /views
- /routes

  - web.php
- /src

  - /Console

    - /Commands
  - /Http

    - /Controllers
  - PackageNameServiceProvider.php

The service provider class is a bit “hack-y” though. I have to do something like this:

```php
class PackageNameServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        if ($this->app->runningInConsole()) {
            $this->defineAssetPublishing();
            $this->defineConsoleCommands();
        }

        if ($this->app->make(Tenant::class)->name == 'This Tenant') {
            $this->defineRoutes();
            $this->defineResources();
        }
    }
}
```

It would be nice if I could get rid of the `if ($this->app->make(Tenant::class)->name == 'This Tenant')` bit. However, it’s working alright for me so far.